# Visual Studio Code window blinks on mouse move (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm running Ubuntu and my Visual Studio Code window blinks randomly when moving mouse over it. What can it be?

Answer (score 2):

Try to start Visual Studio Code with --disable-gpu:

```
/usr/share/code/code --disable-gpu
```